# Can I create multiple ImageViews using a For statement in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a game where the number of ImageViews shown on the page need to be different on different levels.

So the first level might have 4, second level might have 6, etc...

Can I use a For statement to create the ImageViews programmatically?

Such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++{
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
   .......
}
```

Is it possible to do this?  How would I set the ImageView's variable name to be different for each ImageView so that I can call on them later?

If this isn't possible, what are some other design options?  The ImageViews are going to be laid out in a square/rectangle next to each other like a game of match in groups of 4, 6, 8, 12, 14, 16, and 18.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put them in an array:

```
ImageView[] imageViewArray = new ImageView[numImages];

    for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++ ) {
        imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(this);
        imageViewArray[i].setSomething(somethingelse); // unique property for every imageView
    }
```

Comment: You can use the setTag() method of the View superclass to add data to the ImageViews to differentiate them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You should create `TableLayout` and put your `ImageViews` into it. Check [this docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) for more info.